# How add row to gridview in WPF using C#

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview

How add rows to grid-view in WPF,when the grid-view already contains the data.,

```
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT  CName'Name',CLocation'Location',VehicleNo,GasName,Quantity,OrderDate,SupplyDays'Dispatching Day' FROM  View_DailyPlanning "
            + " where  (OrderDate='" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + "' and SupplyDays='" + day + "')", DataAccessBase.GetSqlConnection());
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("View_DailyPlanning");
            da.Fill(dt);
            grid_display.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            grid_display.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
            grid_display.Columns[0].Width = 100;
            grid_display.Columns[1].Width = 150;
            grid_display.Columns[2].Width = 100;
            grid_display.Columns[3].Width = 100;
            grid_display.Columns[4].Width = 100;
            grid_display.Columns[5].Width = 100;
            grid_display.Columns[6].Width = 100;
            grid_display.Items.Add(new Item() { CName = "Someone4", CLocation = "Madivala",VehicleNo="TN2345",Quantity="26",Date="10/07/2014",SupplyDays="Friday"});


ction());
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT  CName'Name',CLocation'Location',VehicleNo,GasName,Quantity,OrderDate,SupplyDays'Dispatching Day' FROM  View_DailyPlanning "
                + " where  (OrderDate='" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + "' and SupplyDays='" + day + "')", DataAccessBase.GetSqlConnection());
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable("View_DailyPlanning");
                da.Fill(dt);
                grid_display.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
                grid_display.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
                grid_display.Columns[0].Width = 100;
                grid_display.Columns[1].Width = 150;
                grid_display.Columns[2].Width = 100;
                grid_display.Columns[3].Width = 100;
                grid_display.Columns[4].Width = 100;
                grid_display.Columns[5].Width = 100;
                grid_display.Columns[6].Width = 100;
                grid_display.Items.Add(new Item() { CName = "Someone4", CLocation = "xxx",VehicleNo="1234",Quantity="26",Date="10/07/2014",SupplyDays="Friday"});
```

How to add additional rows to grid-view,any ideas for do this.,

Answer (score 2):

So from scratch, you can add new rows with the following code

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
if (dt.Columns.Count == 0)
{
    dt.Columns.Add("ColumnA", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("ColumnB", typeof(string));
}

DataRow NewRow = dt.NewRow();
NewRow[0] = "Some Text";
NewRow[1] = "Some Other Text";
dt.Rows.Add(NewRow); 
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridViewl.DataBind();
```

To add additional rows use

```
DataRow NewRow = dt.NewRow();
```

I hope this helps

Comment: @Killercom-Thanks a lot,its woking fine for me,